# Is there a way to auto-capture image upon launching the application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on an Android project named **Emotion Recognition** wherein I want to capture the image using Front Camera as soon as the application is launched.

I am using Camera Activity Intent for capturing the image.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

The idea is to get the user's face while launching the app, as his face would be pointing towards Front Camera. Please help me with this.

Comment: You cannot auto-capture anything via a third-party camera app. You cannot force the user to use the front-facing camera via a third-party camera app.

Comment: What is your question exactly? do you want to have camera in your app without launching another activity?

Comment: @CommosWare It's like developing a safety application. Imagine kids, old-aged people getting depressed, so it's an application to alert their relatives

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar I want a Camera in my app such that, when I launch my app the Camera auto-captures the image using Front-Camera, thus getting User Facial Expressions which can be used for Emotion Recognition

Comment: Have you checked this? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera